# Removing ClearCase vobs

Tags: clearcase

We have a ClearCase server installed on Solaris box and there are several vobs replicated in a multi-site environment. Now as this Clearcase server is becoming old we have setup an new Server on Windows and able to bring that new server into multi-site with all the required vobs. Now we would like to remove/decommission the vobs from old solaris box and want to free up the space occupied by those vobs.

Can any one suggest the best procedure to do this and also point us to the links for that procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- follow the technote "[Moving a VOB using ClearCase MultiSite](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266219)", which basically:

  - creates a replica on the source vob server:
  - import the replica on the destination vob server:

```
multitool mkreplica -export -workdir c:\\
[-maxsize 100m] -fship :
@
```

Import:

```
multitool mkreplica -import -workdir /var/tmp/doesntexist/ -tag
/your/new/vobtag/ -stgloc -auto -npreserve -public /var/adm/atria/
shipping/ms_ship/incoming/
```

- simply `rmtag` and `unregister` the vob on the solaris box, in order to remove it completely from the central registry server.
  See "[How to remove a VOB or View from the ClearCase registry](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21134700)"

The alternative, to delete that vob, and to follow "[Deleting a replica](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/t_delete_replica.htm)"

Then you can simply delete the vob and get back that disk space.