# ClearCase VOBs not being used for a long time

Tags: clearcase

I administer a SCM environment with ClearCase, that has a lot of VOBS.

Many of these VOBS are not used since a long time ago. I would like to know whether it is possible to determine the last modification time on these vobs.

Another doubt is: if I only unregister these VOBS, the CPU and Memory consumption will decrease in the VOB Server?

In theory, to put these vobs online again, I will only have to run a register command, right?

Is there any other approach that you guys could recommend to me to manage this scenario (VOBs not being used for a long time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Many of these VOBS are not used since a long time ago. I would like to know whether it is possible to determine the last modification time on these vobs.

You can try and use [`cleartool lshis -all`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-1-25) on a vob tag.

I had a script which filtered the last events with:

```
cleartool lshis -fmt "%Xn\t%Sd\t%e\t%h\t%u \n" -since 01-Oct-2010 -all <vobname>| grep -v lock | head -1 | grep -o '20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
```

> Another doubt is: if I only unregister these VOBS, the CPU and Memory consumption will decrease in the VOB Server?

Yes, because there wouldn't be anymore vob_server process associated with that vob.

> In theory, to put these vobs online again, I will only have to run a register command, right?

Yes, although I prefer unregister/rmtag (as in "[Removing ClearCase vobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16133215/6309)") before registering and mktagging.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! 
I will test the commands and apply them in our server.